# problems with Indic fonts rending in C# .NET Application

Tags: c#, unicode

I'm trying to display Telugu font string in a C# application. When the text is displayed using a rich textbox or textbox with font set to "Gautami" (one of the fonts that support Telugu language) the characters are broken.

A single letter that is supposed to be displayed on screen is broken in to two characters. What could be the problem?

When the same text is pasted to GMail compose editor or Visual Studio.NET editor, it renders properly. But not on a RichTextBox control of our .NET application. Please see the embedded image that shows the wrong display and expected(correct) display of the text.

[alt text http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/1167/imagena.png](http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/1167/imagena.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a font that supports unicode (i.e. Arial Unicode MS).

Comment: I tried Arial Unicode MS. But no luck. Still the the letters are broken in to two.